# To print a line within the quotes from a text file in java

Tags: java, file-handling

I'm trying to print the text within the quotes in a file. May I have anyone to help me.

E.g : "Jayaramachandiran"

This line is in a text file,and I wanna read it and print it.

Comment: Also, what isn't working?  What is the expected result vs the actual result?

Comment: do you want the code i developed so far?

Comment: Reading the text file line by line.then doing the operations in the text file like addition,..

Comment: ya i could able to read a text file that's working properly.

Comment: But the actual problem is to read the text which is within the codes in that perticular file.e.g if i give PRINT "This is my first demo" in the text file. it should print the text which is in the qoutes alone. like an interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you check out this link:

[How do I create a Java string from the contents of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-to-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file)

It seems someone has answered your question already. :)
The first answer to that question is your best bet.

P.S After reading the file into a string, just go ahead and output the string and voila!

Answer (score 1):

You may use a [BufferedReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) to read.

See this example:

```
import java.io.*;

class YourClass {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader fr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("yourfile.txt"));
        String text = fr.readLine();
        fr.close();

        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to print a string from file, but removing characters, like the quotes, from it.
I think it's better first to read the string from file, then remove the quotes.

Check this [page](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0030.html).